# Exposing angular directive function to another module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have a module with a directive as follows (this is a rough not tested)
I need to implement 3 basic things

1. Configuration for the element that will appear
2. Event listeners that the base controller can use
3. Public methods that the base controller can call

angular.module("componentModule",[]) .directive("myComp",function(){

```
return{
    replace:true,
    template:'<h2>This is my component</h2>',
    scope:{config= "@"},
    link:function(scope,element,attr){
        this.deleteElement = function(id){
        //writing the code to delete this component
        //This is a API function that the user can call to delete
    }
    if (!scope.config.visible){
        //this is a configuration object for the element
        this.visible(false)}
    }
} })
```

then i have my base HTML like containing the directive call like below

```
<div myComm="first" config="eleConfig"></myComp>
<div myComm="second" config="newEleConfig"></myComp>
```

I have a separate controller for my base HTML as follows,

```
angular.module("baseApp",['componentModule'])
 .controller('baseCtrl',function(){
    $scope.eleConfig = {
      visible:true,
      delete:function(e){
        //This is called if we call the delete method 
        } 
     }
    //this is how the delete method is to be called
    $scope.first.deleteElement();
  })
```

**Question**
How to call the deleteElement() method in the baseCtrl as shown above (want to do it the same way KENDO UI does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that angular uses is to expose the directive API to the scope.  This is how ng-model and ng-form both expose ngModelController and ngFormController APIs.

Here is how I would do it:

```
angular.module("componentModule",[])
 .directive("myComp",function($parse){
    return{
        replace:true,
        scope: {
            config: '&'
        },
        template:'<h2>This is my component</h2>',
        controller: function($scope) {
            //Directive API functions should be added to the directive controller here or in the link function (if they need to do DOM manipulation)
        },
        link:function(scope,element, attr, ctrl){
            //add to directive controller

            if(scope.config().visible) {
                //element should be visible, etc.
            }

            ctrl.deleteElement = function(){
                //if this function is called we want to call the config.delete method:

                if(scope.config && scope.config.delete) {
                    //calling the scope.config() method returns the config object from the parent
                    scope.config().delete(element);
                }
            }

            if(attr.myComp) {
                //change to scope.$parent
                scope.$parent[attr.myComp] = ctrl;
            }
        }
      }
   })
```

Assuming markup of:

```
<div my-comp="first" config="configObject"></div>
<div my-comp="second" config="configObject"></div>
```

In your base controller

```
$scope.first.deleteElement();
```

or

```
$scope.second.deleteElement();
```

would delete the appropriate element.

UPDATE:

I've updated the directive based on your updated question.  You want to pass a config object into the directive.  The best way to do that is with an & binding.  If you use the & binding, you need to remember that the directive will create a new scope, and you have to attach the controller to $scope.$parent.

Comment: Hi @joe , I have updated the question as how I would like the directive Apis be accessed. Pls let me know if you have a suggestion.

Comment: I'm not following - it's not clear to me how your original question relates to your update.  Can you clarify?

Comment: thanks,  Seenimurugan has solved my issue regarding Kendo part. What i wanted is basically, have a API function to call the delete fn and also have a event listener in the base app that would listen if the delete function is done. Combining your and Seenimurugan answers solves this issue. Thanks. Now my problem is who to upvote :)

Comment: sorry, but still kinda confused. I have modified my question taking in consideration your and Seenimurugan's answers. Can you please have a look thanks

Comment: Sure - I think I understand what you're after now.  Updated the answer

Comment: Hi , but my markup is like this <div myComp="firstInstance" config="configurations"></div>. how would you do it now ?

Comment: I've updated the answer.  Per angular convention, your directive name (in markup) needs to be my-comp)

Comment: Bro you are "PRO" :D thanks a lot , everything working as needed

Answer (score 1):

In your first requirement, you said you want to write the delete function in the directive, but in the case of KendoUI the actual delete(change) function implementation is done in the base controller and the delete(change) event triggered when the component value changes, which in turn calls the delete function defined in the base controller by the directive. 
If you want to implement something like KendoUI does then look at this

`link to`[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fKo22OvPyImvpZWaRtBg?p=preview)

Switch on the browser console to see the log. KendoUI component's change event happens automatically when the input element changes but in this case i manually triggered the delete event after 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot , this solved one part of my issue. Just one question if use $watch and i have the directive implemented 50 times so the $watch will be called 50 times right ? something better possible ?

Comment: Yes, it will be called 50 times. I used $watch function because i did not listen for any events from the directive element('<h2>This is my component</h2>') itself.  Again as i do not understand your requirement it is difficult to answer for your exact needs.

Comment: thanks for answer, i have remodified my question (took into consideration your last plunker). Please let me know if its clearer.